# Start MonoTouch / MonoDevelop debugger when launch app on device?

Tags: xamarin.ios

In MonoTouch, is there a way to automatically connect to debugger when I launch my app on device via device touch (vs. have debugger launch it for me)? I want to debug launch from push notification alert touch with app completely quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, and it is not planned for the future either.

Feel free to file an enhancement request if you wish though, explaining your use case: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com, we might decide otherwise one day.